# How to get the jquery variable from other function?

Tags: jquery

I declare the global var at top of the script as follow

```
$(function(){
    //Set button disabled
    var macaddr_obj;});
```

I 've a ajax function as follow

```
$('.item-macaddr').live('keyup', function(){
        var vNode  = $(this);           
        var target = $(vNode).parents('tr');    
        var macAddr =  $(target).find('.item-macaddr').val();


        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '" . Yii::app()->createUrl('workorders/check_mac_addr') . "&macAddr=' + macAddr, 
            success: function (data) {                                      
                macaddr_obj = JSON.parse(data);


                if(macaddr_obj.check == 'true')
                {
                    $(target).find('.mac-duplicate-error').text(macaddr_obj.msg);
                    $(target).find('.mac-duplicate-error').addClass('errorMessage');

                    $('#sites-form input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');   
                }else {
                    $(target).find('.mac-duplicate-error').text('');                    
                }
            },          
        });

    });
```

when keyup at other text box, call the function "check_item_row"

```
$('.item-ipaddr').live('keyup', function(){
        var vNode  = $(this);           
        var target = $(vNode).parents('tr');    
        check_item_row(target);         
    });
```

This is the function to use macaddr_obj

```
var check_item_row = function(target)
    {
        alert(macaddr_obj.check);
}
```

I want to use the value of macaddr_obj. How can I do?

Comment: `macaddr_obj` is not actually global. It is local to your `ready` handler.

Comment: `macaddr_obj` is local to the ready handler in which it is declared

Comment: Remove the `var` from the `var macaddr_obj;` declaration. This would give it global scope (although it is not really good practice to have your variables available globally)

Comment: since you are using an ajax request to populate `macaddr_obj` there is no assurance that by the time the `item-ipaddr` keyup is fired the value is populated

Comment: Does your current code trigger an error ? if yes, which one ?

Comment: anyway since in your success hander since you have not used `var` to declare the `macaddr_obj` variable it will be global variab;e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just put your `check_item_row` function declaration inside the `$(function(){ ... })` block, along with the handlers declaration :

```
$(function(){
    //Set button disabled
    var macaddr_obj;

    ...

    var check_item_row = function(target) {
        alert(macaddr_obj.check);
    }

    ...

    // ".live()" is deprecated, use the following syntax with ".on()" :
    $(document).on('keyup', '.item-macaddr', function(){
        ...
    });

    $(document).on('keyup', '.item-ipaddr', function(){
        ...
    });

});
```

From your code, it appears that `macaddr_obj` will only be initialized after at least one ajax call has been triggered, and successfully returned a value.

If you call `check_item_row` *before* that, it will trigger a `TypeError: macaddr_obj is undefined`.

One simple way to avoid this is to initialize the object with a default value :

```
var macaddr_obj = {};  // 'macaddr_obj.check' will return 'undefined',
                       // which probably fits your needs
 // or
var macaddr_obj = {check: false}; // 'macaddr_obj.check' will return 'false'
```

Answer (score 1):

Define your macaddr_obj globally:

```
var macaddr_obj;

$(function(){
    //Set button disabled
...........

});
```